# Unable to publish geocoding service [ERROR: 001369]

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, geocoding

I manage to create a geo locator on arcmap and tested it.

but when I publish to arcgis server using arcmap or arcgis server manager. I encounter the error

1) Fail to publish service.

The error is very generic on logs.

may I know is there anyway to to troubeshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if its crashing or simplying trowing error in ArcGIS Server logs. If its crashing and creating the DMP files under C:\arcgisserver\logs\\errorreports path then open that DMP file with Visual Studio to see the error message.

This majorly due to AGS account access to your local machine AGS directory. As per ESRI below mention step can be used to resolve it, but its a general stpe -

To run this, on the ArcGIS for Server Machine simply Navigate to 'Start -> All Programs -> ArcGIS -> ArcGIS 10.x.x for Server -> Configure ArcGIS Server Account'. When prompted simply re-enter the password for the account list which runs your Server services.

You need to check you data source and access to that as well. Refer below mention link as well -

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/common-problems-and-solutions.htm

search for 001369 error and same you need to check in ArcGIS Server logs.